# Someone famous retweeted me couple of years ago, how do I find it through advanced twitter search?

Tags: twitter, search, account-management, twitter-search, bitcoin

On Twitter, @Someone famous retweeted me some couple of years ago. I did not care for it then, but now I want to find it.
I tried things like from:@famousguy filter:nativeretweets [@me]
which did not work.
I also tried (from:famousguy) (to:me) to no avail.
Any ideas?

Comment: What if he did not? As far as I remember, he just retweeted my tweet, which was something from  cointelegraph or coindesk or something.

Comment: In that case, if you see your own tweet you can know about the date. Filter his tweets by dates.

Comment: My previous comment was an answer to someone who said what if the guy deleted the tweet? and then he deleted that comment. My answer sounds like something else now, lol. My original question remains as I cannot find my original tweet either using keywords. It was something about bitcoiners being in a government themselves, governing themselves, all with smart contracts, without the need for a central entity.

Comment: I was the one :) I deleted the previous comment. In continuation to my first comment and its reply, is the second comment useful for your problem?

Comment: Sorry, it is not. I tried to find my own tweet, I could not. The only parameters I have on hand are the guy's Twitter handle who retweeted me and my handle.